# R - substring by number

Tags: r

what is the most easiest way how to get number from string? I have huge list of links like this, I need to get that number 98548 from it.

```
https://address.com/admin/customers/98548/contacts
```

Note that number cant have different count of numbers and can start from 0 to 9

Comment: Try `gsub("\\D+", "", x)`

Answer (score 2):

This is the most easiest that I know :

```
 str <- "https://address.com/admin/customers/98548/contacts"
 str_extract_all(str, "\\d+")[[1]]
```

Comment: `simplify = T` returns a `character`.

Comment: You better not name the vector `str`

Comment: Right, 'str' might not be a best choice here, will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`:

```
no="https://address.com/admin/customers/98548/contacts"   
 unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(no,"\\d{1,}"))
  [1] "98548"
```

Comment: `simplify` avoids the use of `unlist()`, just FYI.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about that option. I will remember it going forward.